# Exclude some files on svn command line commit (not svn:ignore)

Tags: svn, commit, ignore, revert

I'm developing with many people.

I check out remote repository, get 3 file. After edit, run:

```
svn status
```

It shows:

```
M file_1
M file_2
M file_3
```

Now, I want to commit only two file: file_1, file_2, but not file_3.

How to do it?

I dont' want to use

```
svn revert file_3
```

before commit.

Explain: I edit file_1, file_2 for shared project, file_3 for running on only my local machine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

```
$ svn commit file_1 file_2
```

Comment: Ok so if I've got 100 files I want to commit and only want to exclude one. Is there a way?

Comment: Just use the shell, like let SVN list all the modified files and grep -v the single one.

Answer (score 12):

Expanding upon zoul's answer.. to develop your list of files use:

```
svn stat |  grep -v ignore.file | perl -ne 'chop; s/^.\s+//; print "$_ "'
```

Or if you have file names with spaces use:

```
svn stat |  grep -v ignore.file | perl -ne 'chop; s/^.\s+//; print "\"$_\" "'
```

Comment: svn stat , show us what files we have to commit and we just need choose the ones , thks.

Comment: Thanks for actually providing a useful answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

one line for bash:

```
svn ci $(svn stat | grep -v exclude.file)
```

Comment: I'd change this to svn ci $(svn stat | grep -v ^?| grep -v exclude.file) , just to filter out files that are not in the repository, like binaries built from the sources. Otherwise, svn will complain about them and will not commit anything, with error messages similar to svn: E200009: 'a.file' is not under version control

Comment: This doesn't work because of the file status letter at the beginning of each line.
You have to use this instead:

`svn ci $(svn stat | grep -v exclude.file | awk '{print $2}')`

Answer (score 1):

Just append the paths of the files to commit to the svn commit command:

```
svn commit file_1 file_2
```

See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.commit.html

Answer (score 1):

I wound up making a script containing the following:

```
svn ci $(svn diff --summarize | \
    grep -v exclude.file1 | \
    grep -v exclude.file2 | \
    ...
    grep -v exclude.fileN \
)
```

I'm sure someone can make it even more flexible by making this script read a file which would contain a list of files to be excluded from the commit.

Comment: You da real MVP. This is the only one that works when externals are involved. Otherwise, you pick up extra lines with garbage like "status".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a windows powershell version that commits only files that aren't in a changelist. Create a changelist called ignore-on-commit (which Tortoise SVN will understand anyway) and put the files you don't want to commit into it.

```
# get list of changed files into targets
[XML]$svnStatus = svn st -q --xml C:\SourceCode\Monad
# select the nodes that aren't in a changelist
$fileList = $svnStatus.SelectNodes('/status/target/entry[wc-status/@item != "unversioned"]') | Foreach-Object {$_.path};
# create a temp file of targets
$fileListPath =  [IO.Path]::GetTempFileName();
$fileList | out-file $fileListPath -Encoding ASCII
# do the commit
svn commit --targets $fileListPath -m "Publish $version" --keep-changelists 
# remove the temp file
Remove-Item $filelistPath
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use this command.

```
svn ci `svn st | grep -e "^[A|M]" | grep -v "test.js" | grep -ve "conf\.js$" | awk '{print $2}' | tr "\\n" " "`
```

Comment: Does not work when there are spaces  in filenames, as AWK will not print the entire filename